# Magento 2.4.5-p1: Bug when open Associated Product grid

Tags: magento2

sometimes i got this bug when open Associated Product grid of a configurable product have more than 500 child products

[image]

I tried research and truncate bookmark table but it's not work for me

Then i checked with other configurable products, which ones with less child products than, all others product can open

So i guess problem is this product have too much child product because i have look at request, too much params sending, request error ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

[image]

How i can solved it? Any idea? Thanks all

Comment: Any idea? I really confused